# Photo streaming uploading protocol

Tags: networking, protocols

In this age of *chat applications and various messaging software, I was wondering if there is already an official protocol (RFC) that would follow the following basic flow:

1. Client connects to Server for a new session
2. Client uploads an image (or video) with metadata information (size, resolution, format) to server
3. Server does some work (not part of the protocol)
4. Server replies with REJECT then client goes to 1.
5. Server replies with ACCEPT then client stops and gather the result as part of the reply from the server

I have a proprietary solution now that does the basic (supports basic formats) and as we know, the devil is in the details so I wonder if some existing protocol would cover the stream format and more unhappy paths I may have missed with this simple design.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any protocol that can handle file probing for you ..

ffprobe is a good open source solution to do this but requires processing power and scale.

So this step must be done on server side, after the upload. You cannot trust the client for such information.

I suggest the cloud approach. Here, we're using Amazon Cloud.

Upload your file to AWS S3. You can use multi part upload for faster upload. No need to scale anything, AWS will do it for you. 
Your clients just request a signed URL from your web server. The server return the URL and an ID for this new asset. Your clients upload to AWS S3 using the URL.

Once the upload is done, your client make a call to your server again to say: "I'm done with Asset ID blah". Your server knows the asset is now uploaded and can initiate transcoding, analysis, DB updates, etc.

We do this exact scenario in our project. 
For transcoding at scale we use our own open source project: https://github.com/sportarchive/CloudTranscode

This is not an easy business, especially if you want to handle videos.

If you restrict yourself to pictures, then a lot can be done on the user side. You can create several versions of the image in JS, directly in the browser for example or in the mobile app, and upload them to your server. The load is much smaller and you may not need this decoupled architecture.

If you handle videos, you need a solid backend.

Hope this help